# Embedding Power BI dashboard in an email

Tags: email, powerbi

I have developed a dashboard in Power BI that I would like to embed in an email body - Outlook, Gmail etc. Is this possible please and has anyone been successful at doing this?

Answer (score 0):

No, embedding requires a lot of javascript code and a modern browser to work. Currently it is not possible to get this working in an e-mail body, because it will violate event basic security policies. Embed it in a web application hosted somewhere (or if the recipients has access to it, you can leave it in Power BI Service) and send and link to it (you can add an image if you want) in the e-mail.